# Route to action of controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Previous i used:

```
data: {autocomplete_source: categories_path} %>
```

To point to the action index in categories controller.All worked fine!

Now i created an new action in categories controller

```
def search
@categories = Category.order(:name).where("name like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")

render json: @categories.map(&:name)
end
```

And tried to point to that action:

```
data: {autocomplete_source: search_categories_path} %>
```

But i get the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `search_categories_path' for #<#<Class:0x51844c8>:0x5375820>
```

What did i wrong? Thanks!

My routes:

```
     products GET    /products(.:format)            products#index
          POST   /products(.:format)            products#create
 new_product GET    /products/new(.:format)        products#new
edit_product GET    /products/:id/edit(.:format)   products#edit
  product GET    /products/:id(.:format)        products#show
          PUT    /products/:id(.:format)        products#update
          DELETE /products/:id(.:format)        products#destroy
 categories GET    /categories(.:format)          categories#index
          POST   /categories(.:format)          categories#create
new_category GET    /categories/new(.:format)      categories#new
edit_category GET    /categories/:id/edit(.:format) categories#edit
 category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)      categories#show
          PUT    /categories/:id(.:format)      categories#update
          DELETE /categories/:id(.:format)      categories#destroy
```

Routes:

```
Autorails::Application.routes.draw do
resources :products


resources :categories do
 collection do
    :search
 end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have something like this in your `routes.rb`:

```
resources :categories do
  collection do
    get :search
  end
end
```

Comment: @EmSta add also contents of your `routes.rb`.

Comment: @EmSta did you restart your application server after editing `routes.rb`?

Comment: That should be `get :search` in the block.

Comment: @bgates of course it should be. Thanks and sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Check `rake routes` if that route really exists under that name.
For more information see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers

Comment: I updated my question with the routes! So what do i have to change? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this

```
resources :categories do
  collection do
    get :search
  end
end
```